# After installing gitosis on my server I cannot access through SSH

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, git

I installed a local server for my office intranet and after installing git and gitosis to use it as a repository I cannot access it through ssh. I won't accept the credentials. I edited the ssh configuration file to allow the main user in the ubuntu machine and after a reboot it worked, but hasn't worked after that even if a reboot and restart the ssh server again. What is it that I could be doing wrong? Thanks

Comment: Please tell me you set up gitosis for the git user and not your main account. The way you use `sudo ssh` tells me there may be some confusion.

Answer (score 0):

An install of gitosis does not allow remote SSH access to the `git` account if you try something like this:

```
 $ ssh gitosis.host.com -l git
```

Also, did you install gitosis from `apt-get` (or `aptitude`), or did you install it from source? I have never been able to get the Ubuntu-provided package to work properly; installing from source has always worked flawlessly, for me.

Comment: From source. It won't allow login from any account whatsoever. So I have to plugin my keyboard, mouse and monitor to the server every time I need to change something. Which is annoying.

Comment: Seems like a silly question, but I'm just trying to troubleshoot this: did you follow the installation instructions on the gitosis homepage?

Comment: Yes. In fact that was the way I installed it. Everything works ok. The repos and de configuration method of pushing the files works like a charm. The only problem is that whenever I try to ssh to the server, it says that there is a problem with gitosis and doesn't allow the connection. If I do sudo ssh user@host it connects, but won't allow the login with the accounts password.

Comment: So, if you try to `ssh user@host` it works, but `ssh git@host` does not work? As I mentioned before, you cannot SSH into the `git` account, used by gitosis.

Answer (score 0):

Gitosis is unmaintained and deprecated in favor of [gitolite](https://github.com/sitaramc/gitolite) which you might have better luck with, especially since it has better error messages, debugging capabilities, and documentation.